# How to match a changing pattern in python?

Tags: python, regex

So I have a collection of lyrics from different artists, but in the middle of all the lyrics there is always an advertisement I want to remove. It looks like this:

'lyric lyric See John Mayer LiveGet tickets as low as $53 lyric lyric'

More generally, the pattern is always: 'See ARTIST LiveGet tickets as low as $NUMBER'

Is there a way I can match this changing pattern so I can get rid of these advertisements in the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: fixed so it removes the space where the text was removed.

Assuming the ad is ALWAYS in that format, this is a very simplified version that you could expand upon..

```
import re

lyrics = "lyric lyric See John Mayer Live Get tickets as low as $53 lyric lyric"

pattern = r'See\s+(.*?)\s+Live Get tickets as low as\s+\$[\d,]+'

clean_lyrics = re.sub(pattern, '', lyrics).strip()
clean_lyrics = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', clean_lyrics)

print(clean_lyrics)
# Output: 'lyric lyric lyric lyric'
```

The **\s+** , **.*?** , **\d+** are whitespaces, any random characters in a group, and digits in that order. This is used to help identify a pattern.